# How can I convert nested dictionary to pd.dataframe faster?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a json file which looks like this

```
{
    "file": "name",
    "main": [{
        "question_no": "Q.1",
        "question": "what is ?",
        "answer": [{
                "user": "John",
                "comment": "It is defined as",
                "value": [
                          {
                            "my_value": 5,
                            "value_2": 10
                          },
                          {
                            "my_value": 24,
                            "value_2": 30
                          }
                          ]
            },
            {
                "user": "Sam",
                "comment": "as John said above it simply means",
                "value": [
                          {
                            "my_value": 9,
                            "value_2": 10
                          },
                          {
                            "my_value": 54,
                            "value_2": 19
                          }
                          ]
            }
        ],
        "closed": "no"
    }]
}
```

desired result:

```
Question_no      question  my_value_sum      value_2_sum       user      comment
Q.1             what is ?      29                40            john    It is defined as
Q.1             what is ?      63                29            Sam     as John said above it simply means
```

What I have tried is `data = json_normalize(file_json, "main")` and then using a for loop like

```
for ans, row in data.iterrows():
    ....
    ....
    df = df.append(the data)
```

But the issue using this is that it is taking a lot of time that my client would refuse the solution. there is around 1200 items in the `main` list and there are 450 json files like this to convert. So this intermediate process of conversion would take almost an hour to complete.

**EDIT:
is it possible to get the sum of the `my_value` and `value_2` as a column? (updated the desired result also)**

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: I can't be sure without knowing more details about your problem. But try appending the data to lists first, then only create the df at the end like `df = pd.DataFrame(question_numbers, questions, users, comments)`.

Comment: @Datanovice its corrected now

Comment: @DominicD but then the users and comments will be nested list right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select dictionary by `main` with parameter `record_path` and `meta`:

```
data = pd.json_normalize(file_json["main"], 
                         record_path='answer', 
                         meta=['question_no', 'question'])
print (data)
   user                             comment question_no   question
0  John                    It is defined as         Q.1  what is ?
1   Sam  as John said above it simply means         Q.1  what is ?
```

Then if order is important convert last N columns to first positions:

```
N = 2
data = data[data.columns[-N:].tolist() + data.columns[:-N].tolist()]
print (data)
  question_no   question  user                             comment
0         Q.1  what is ?  John                    It is defined as
1         Q.1  what is ?   Sam  as John said above it simply means
```

Comment: You are a life saver bro! No wonder why you have such high rep.

Comment: Is it possible to get the sum of ```my_value``` and ```value_2``` inside the nested list ```value``` somehow? I have edited the desired result. Please check it out

Comment: @jezael actually I was going to post a quesiton. But had to wait 90 mintues to post another question. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064879/how-to-access-a-nested-dictionary-which-is-a-row-in-a-dataframe I have slightly modified to include a ```submitted``` key inside the values to match my exact situation. If you could please answer it there. It would make sense for the headline and people with same issue

Comment: @Derik81 - Thank you, but seems json is not valid, just tested in [link](https://jsonlint.com/).